# How do you initialize DocumentDB client as a Singleton in a dotnet core application

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am building a MVC Web application in .net core and will be using CosmosDB with the DocumentDB API.  I keep reading that for preformance you should

> Use a singleton DocumentDB client for the lifetime of your application Note that each DocumentClient instance is thread-safe and performs efficient connection management and address caching when operating in Direct Mode. To allow efficient connection management and better performance by DocumentClient, it is recommended to use a single instance of DocumentClient per AppDomain for the lifetime of the application.

but I am unsure of how to do this.

I will using the following code to inject my services into my controllers, which each correspond to a different collection.

```
services.AddScoped<IDashboard, DashboardService>();
services.AddScoped<IScheduler, SchedulerService>();
services.AddScoped<IMailbox, MailboxService>();
```

How do I create the DocumentDB client as a Singleton and inject/use it in these services?

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to use a similar approach:

```
services.AddSingleton<IDocumentClient>(x => new DocumentClient(UriEndpoint, MasterKey));
```

Then in your Controllers, you could inject the client simply by:

```
private readonly IDocumentClient _documentClient;
public HomeController(IDocumentClient documentClient){
    _documentClient = documentClient;
}
```

Comment: What to do for multiple cosmosDB configurations? and I want to use the same Interface

Comment: You would need to implement a class (maybe a Factory) that can hold all the different clients with different configurations and a method to ask for the client instance that you want on runtime